# Parsing delimited list of tokens using Boost Spirit Qi

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit-qi

Using boost::spirit::qi I'm trying to parse lines consisting of a label followed by a variable number of delimited tokens. I'm calling the grammar with **phrase_parse** and using the provided **blank** parser as skip parser to preserve newlines as I need to make sure the label is the first item on each line.

The simple base case:

```
label token, token, token
```

Can be parsed with the grammar:

```
line = label >> (token % ',') >> eol;
```

The problem I am facing is that the grammar should accept zero or more tokens and that tokens may be empty. The grammar should accept the following lines:

```
label
label ,
label , token
label token, , token,
```

I have not managed to create a grammar that accepts all examples above.
Any suggestions on how to solve this?

**Edit:**

Thanks to sehe for all input on the problem stated above.
Now for the fun part that I forgot to include...
The grammar should also accept empty lines and split lines. (tokens without a label)
When I try to make the label optional, I get an infinite loop matching the empty string.

```
label

label token
token
```

Comment: I suggest you use ANTLR instead.  I realize this isn't the answer you were hoping for, so I'm posting it as a comment.  ANTLR is a lot easier to use in the long term, has better tool support, and more references to learn from.

Comment: @JohnZwinck We get that you don't like Spirit by now. There's a lot not to like about it (and about c++ in general). That's fine. But suggesting to use a ANTLR here, without any context outside the question stated is also a bit ludicrous. Sounds bit like bringing a canon to swat a fly.

Comment: It's more like telling someone who is asking a question about russian grammar he should switch to english instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to accept the empty list with

```
line = label >> -(token % ',') >> eol;
```

Note that `eol` won't work if your skipper skips eol too (so don't use `qi::space` but e.g. `qi::blank` for this purpose)

Also, depending on the definition of `token` you should maybe change it to accept the "empty" token as well

---

In response to the comment: a fully working sample **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0979e31dcc92bd2d)**

```
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

int main()
{
    using namespace qi;

    using It     = std::string::const_iterator;
    using Token  = std::string;
    using Tokens = std::vector<Token>;

    rule<It, blank_type> label 
        = lexeme[+~char_(":")] >> ':'
        ;

    rule<It, Token(), blank_type> token
        = lexeme[*~char_(",\n")];
        ;

    rule<It, Tokens(), blank_type> line
        = label >> -(token % ',') >> eol
        ;

    for (std::string const input : {
        "my first label: 123, 234, 345 with spaces\n",
        "1:\n",
        "2: \n",
        "3: ,,,\n",
        "4: ,  \t ,,\n",
        "5: ,  \t , something something,\n",
    })
    {
        std::cout << std::string(40, '=') << "\nparsing: '" << input << "'\n";

        Tokens parsed;
        auto f = input.begin(), l = input.end();
        bool ok = phrase_parse(f, l, line, blank, parsed);

        if (ok)
        {
            std::cout << "Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: " << parsed.size() << "\n";
            for (auto token : parsed)
                std::cout << "token value '" << token << "'\n";
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Parse failed\n";

        if (f != l)
            std::cout << "Remaining input: '" << std::string(f, l) << "'\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
========================================
parsing: 'my first label: 123, 234, 345 with spaces
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 3
token value '123'
token value '234'
token value '345 with spaces'
========================================
parsing: '1:
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 1
token value ''
========================================
parsing: '2: 
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 1
token value ''
========================================
parsing: '3: ,,,
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 4
token value ''
token value ''
token value ''
token value ''
========================================
parsing: '4: ,       ,,
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 4
token value ''
token value ''
token value ''
token value ''
========================================
parsing: '5: ,       , something something,
'
Tokens parsed successfully, number parsed: 4
token value ''
token value ''
token value 'something something'
token value ''
```

Comment: It's when I try to add a rule for "empty" token that things break. Even a really simple rule like `token = -lit("token")` fails. Could you provide an example?

Comment: @Fredrik I've added a sample (I just realized that `*(char_ - ',' - eol)` would be a bit more accurate for a token, but you can decide that :))

Comment: On a side note: How do I debug spirit::qi grammars? I have seen some comments about using certain #defines to activate debug blurbs but I never got that working...

Comment: Ahh... this time the google-fu was with me and I found the answer immediately. Just call `debug(rule)`.

Comment: @Fredrik I'd suggest the much friendlier BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE and BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES macros: `BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((label)(token)(line))`

Comment: Regarding the edits, if you have more questions, please post them on the main site.